# JavaFX - css does not work in my project

Tags: java, css, javafx

I faced with the problem when I can't use the second css file by some evil reason.
I use **IntelliJ IDEA 14 (build 139.222) Ultimate edition**.
I use **JavaFX 2.0** which built-in in IntelliJ IDEA 139.222 build
**Board.css** does not work. **LoginForm.css** works fine.
Also I've added the ;?*.css resource pattern into Compiler Section.

**btn** is the button which I click being at the **Login Form**.
Instead of **GameApp** class(it's the class which is inherited from **Application** class),
I used **getClass()** method and even some other classes. No result.

the css I tried to use in Board.css is **.button:hover {-fx-background-color: white;}**
}

Here's the code:

```
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(GameApp.class.getResource("/sample/buttonGrid.fxml"));
            root.getStylesheets().add(GameApp.class.getResource("/sample/Board.css").toExternalForm());
            currentStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            currentStage.setResizable(false);
            currentStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    this.currentStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    initPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 698, 364);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(GameApp.class.getResource("LoginForm.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

This one does not work too:

```
        try {
            Pane pane = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(GameApp.class.getResource("/sample/buttonGrid.fxml"));
            pane.getStylesheets().add("/sample/Board.css");
            currentStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
            currentStage.setResizable(false);
            currentStage.show();

        }
```

Board.css is:

```
.button:hover {
     -fx-background-color: white;
 }
```

Comment: Which JavaFX version are you using? There were some issues applying stylesheets to `Parent`s in earlier versions. Assuming you are seeing no error messages, try adding the stylesheet to the `Scene` instead of to the root node.

Comment: I don't know. JavaFX was built-in in Intellij IDEA. I am dealing with this one week : ). Let me check. Oh, I made some FXML files in JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 which runs under Windows 8.

Comment: Do what? Add the stylesheet to the scene? Just do as you did in your start method: `root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(...);` `Scene scene = new Scene(root);` `scene.getStylesheets().add(GameApp.getClass().getResource(...)...);` `currentStage.setScene(scene);`

Comment: Yes, to add the stylesheet. Am I did it right ?

Comment: I use JavaFX 2.0 which built-in in IntelliJ IDEA 139.222 build

Comment: I would recommend using a more recent version. If you are forced to use Java 7, use JavaFX 2.2. For the stylesheet, your code is adding it to the root node, not to the scene. If I remember correctly, this didn't work well in previous releases.

Comment: recent version of what ? IntelliJ IDEA ? JavaFX Scene Builder ? I can use whatever I can cause I have no restrictions. Also, you said I use right code. I made the scene in Scene builder cause it's much  faster and easier.

Comment: Your `start` method adds the stylesheet to the scene. Your button handler is different; it adds it to the root node. Adding to the root node did not work well in early JavaFX 2 versions. Change your button handler so it looks like your `start` method.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of JavaFX had some issues adding stylesheets to `Parent` nodes, instead of adding them to the `Scene` directly. The code in your action handler for the button adds the stylesheet to the node.

I would recommend making sure you are using a suitably recent version of the JDK and JavaFX; preferably Java 8 (which comes bundled with JavaFX 8). If you are forced to use Java 7, then make sure you have the most recent version, which is bundled with JavaFX 2.2. Simply updating your JDK version may solve the problem.

Also try adding the stylesheet directly to the scene, instead of to the root node:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(GameApp.class.getResource("/sample/buttonGrid.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(GameApp.class.getResource("/sample/Board.css").toExternalForm());
            currentStage.setScene(scene);
            currentStage.setResizable(false);
            currentStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Now I added the stylesheet directrly to the Scene object. That's you meant ?                 try {
                    Pane pane = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(GameApp.class.getResource("/sample/buttonGrid.fxml"));
                    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
                    scene.getStylesheets().add("/sample/Board.css");
                    currentStage.setScene(scene);
                    currentStage.setResizable(false);
                    currentStage.show();

                }

Comment: I use JDK 1.8.0_25 and JavaFX 2.0.

Comment: That seems highly unlikely, unless you have a very strange setup. Java 8 (JDK 1.8.0) comes with JavaFX 8 already included. Can you do `System.out.println(System.getProperty("javafx.version"));` to confirm that. If you are really using JavaFX 2.0 you need to fix your project setup.

Comment: Yeah. It shows that I have "8.0.25" version. JDK version simply to check when you create the new JavaFX project. You can choose what's the JDK you want to use...

Comment: And still doesn't work with the changes outlined above? No error message? (No null pointer exception?)

Comment: Yes. Maybe I misunderstood something ? I can upload the project somewhere.

Comment: Don't upload your entire project (no-one will read all your code...). Create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from scratch that displays the same behavior, and edit your question with it.